# Why do certain formulas in google sheets not work when a google form is linked in the same document?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-forms

I have a google form linked document with 2 sheets (1 with a linked form, 1 without). If I try using some formulas (`SUMIF` or `QUERY`) in the sheet that is not linked I get a "Formula parse error", additionally the syntax highlighting bugs out when typing a `SUMIF` formula.

For reference, this is the exact sheet and formula I am trying:

[image: Example]

However, If I copy and paste the exact contents of this sheet to another google sheets document, then the `SUMIF` just works. Does having a google form linked sheet in the same document affect the other sheets?

Answer (score 2):

you sheet has non-english locale therefore you need to use semicolon `;` instead of commas `,` in formula syntaxes

[image]

- if you use `;` in non-english sheets = all is ok
- if you use `;` in english sheets = all is ok - all `;` are autocorrected into `,`
- if you use `,` in english sheets = all is ok
- if you use `,` in non-english sheets = you got a syntax error

also keep in mind that arrays `{}` have its own syntax universe...

- in english sheets you use `,` to stack stuff next to each other
- in english sheets you use `;` to stack stuff under each other
- in non-english sheets you use `\` to stack stuff next to each other
- in non-english sheets you use `;` to stack stuff under each other

anyway, if you are not sure what to use either check the settings or you can take a hint from the formula tooltip helper box:

[image]